# Django unique_together throwing server errors, not sure why

Tags: python, mysql, django, multithreading

Okay here is some background, we have built a messaging system for our app using django and mysql. We have built in read_receipts to tell a user when a thread needs to be read. We create a read_receipt whenever our API endpoint get_messages is called, and it returns any new messages. In the app if a user has a thread open then get_messages is called every 5 seconds. A read receipt is meant to be unique to a thread and user (ie. only one read_receipt per thread and user, but a thread or a user can 'own' multiple read_receipts). We have been running into a server error every so often where a read_receipt with the same thread and user as another read_receipt is attempting to be created. The only place we create read_receipts is in create_individual_message_read_receipt() which I posted below. I'm stumped because the code should ensure a read_receipt has been deleted for a user, and thread if it exists before it creates another one. Any ideas? I think it may be related to the frequency of the calls, but we had hoped the transactions would have solved that.

```
class IndividualMessageThreadReadReceipt(models.Model):
"""
Stores whether user has read the most recent message
"""

    thread = models.ForeignKey(
    IndividualMessageThread, related_name='read_receipts')

    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User')

    last_read_message = models.ForeignKey('messages.IndividualMessage')

    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta(object):
        ordering = ('id',)
        unique_together = ('user', 'thread')



@transaction.commit_manually()
def create_individual_message_thread_read_receipt(individual_thread,
                                              message, user):
"""
create message read receipt between individuals, deletes the old
receipt so the receipt should be unique for the user and thread
"""
    try:
        ind_read_receipt = (IndividualMessageThreadReadReceipt.objects
                            .select_for_update().get(
                                thread=individual_thread.id,
                                user=user.id))
        if ind_read_receipt.last_read_message_id < message.id:
            ind_read_receipt.delete()
            IndividualMessageThreadReadReceipt.objects.create(
                thread=individual_thread, last_read_message=message,
                user=user)
    except IndividualMessageThreadReadReceipt.DoesNotExist:
        IndividualMessageThreadReadReceipt.objects.create(
            thread=individual_thread, last_read_message=message, user=user)
    transaction.commit()
```